# Wordpress Timber (TWIGG) - How do I apply a template to a bunch of pages if parent is the same

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

Basically I want to apply a template to the child pages of a specified page in Timber, Wordpress.

I have been currently using page-(name of the page).twig to apply templates to specific pages but this only changes one page at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this answers your question but you can make a php file that calls a twig file that has the layout you would like to use for the pages. You then add "Template Name: *Your Template Name*" in doc blocks in that php file. You can then choose to use that template in the wordpress admin panel when creating a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out

If I create a page called contact, I will have to create a twig called page-contact.twig otherwise it will default to base.twig

```
$templates = array('base.twig');

if ($post){
    array_unshift($templates, 'page-' . $post->post_name . '.twig');
}
```

If homepage, switch to front-page.twig

```
if (is_home()){
    array_unshift($templates, 'front-page.twig');
}
```

If 404, switch to 404.twig

```
if (is_404()){
    array_unshift($templates, '404.twig');
}
```

If I create a page called contact and a subpage called location then the following code will get the name of the parent page and put child-page- before it so it doesn't clash with the other template. Any page below contact will use the template child-page-contact.twig

```
if ($post->post_parent !== 0) {
    array_unshift($templates, 'child-page-' . $post_data->post_name . '.twig');
}
```